# Outlook office addin: Email subject fails as a valid file name

Tags: regex, outlook, filenames, mailitem

I am developing an outlook addin which saves the email as `.eml` file in an in-house application. The email file name is default to the subject of the email.

The API throws the error

> `bad file name error message`

when I set the file name to the email Subject.

However, if I mannually console the email subject and give it as the file name, it works. I tried looking for any special characters and could not find anything. Even the simple subjects such as `test mail` does not work.

Our back end team validates the file name with the following regular expression:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\s_-]{1,240}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant snippet of your code as well as the message subject that fails.